# Median as pivot selection halves array into one third and two thirds

Tags: algorithms, quicksort

Selecting the median as an approach for pivot selection halves the array into $T(\frac n3)$ and  $T(\frac{2n}{3})$, so our $T(n)$ becomes:

$$T(n) = T(\frac{2n}{3})+ T(\frac n3)$$

Solution:

**Approach 1**: using master method, it's **CASE 1** gives and **upper bound**:

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) = T(\frac{2n}{3})+ T(\frac n3) + O(n)\\
\le 2 T(\frac{2n}{3})+ n\\
\le 2 T(\frac{n}{\frac 32})+ n\\
\vdots\\
=O(\log_{\frac 32}{2})\\
\\
\end{align}
$$

**Approach 2**: using recursion tree, we sum up levels till we get:

$$\text{Level } k: \sum_{i=0}^k\binom ki \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k-i}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^i = \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \right)^kcn$$

Since we have left subtree with $\frac n3$ doing less work than right subtree $\frac {2n}{3}$ as $\frac 32 > \frac 13$, we could derive a **lower bound**: for left subtree and an **upper bound**: for the right subtree. So, we could multiple each level on the right by $n$ to get $O(n\log_{\frac 32}{n})$ and similarily for lower bound.

**Problem**:

- We get different upper bounds in approach 1 and approach 2, what do you think please?

**Edit**: case 1 in approach 1 one implies $O(n^{\log_{\frac 32}{2}})$.

Comment: Approach 1 is wrong. The master theorem doesn't imply that $T(n) = O(1)$ in your case. In fact, it doesn't apply at all to your recurrence.

Comment: Also, you're using a difference recurrence in Approach 1 than in the prequel.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. Sorry for mistake. I meant $O(n^{\log_{\frac 32}{2}})$. So it's still has different answer from approach 2, what do you think please?

Comment: The recurrence can’t be solved using the master theorem, since it’s not of the correct form.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. Oh. I see that both $a, b  \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thanks. I found similar solution from another course as well!

Comment: Please be more explicit: Why&how would *Median as pivot selection* split the *array into one third and two thirds* (Why not into halves)? Does this refer to any particular implementation of *partition*? What exactly do the bounds discussed limit?

Comment: @greybeard. Hello. Thank you for the questions. It's given by the question not me. So, I would assume that yes this is their specification of pivot.